# My favourite two number sequences are below do you know/ can you guess them and what are yours?

Tags: number-sequence

3.3.5.4.4.3.5.5.4.3.6.6... and
8, 5, 4, 9, 1, 7, 6, 3, 2, 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sequence is

> the number of letters in each number in ascending order from one. For example, 'one' has 3 letters, 'two' also has three letters, 'three' has five letters, and so on.

The second sequence is

> the numbers between 0 and 10 in alphabetical order, when spelt out in English. That is, 'eight' comes before 'five', 'four', and so on. 'Zero' is the last number alphabetically.